# How to convert a Tensorflow model checkpoint to Pytorch?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, pytorch, imagenet

I'm working with a Deep Learning model which has a ResNet-50 as backbone pretrained on ImageNet. The dataset that I'm using is the CUB-200, which is a set of 200 species of birds. For this reason I think that could be good to have a pretrained model on a dataset that has a similar domain and I found that the iNaturalist one could be the one that I'm looking for.

The problem is that I didn't find any pretrained model for Pytorch, but only a Tensorflow one [here](https://github.com/richardaecn/cvpr18-inaturalist-transfer).

I tried to convert it using the MDNN library, but it needs also the '.ckpt.meta' file extend and I have only the '.ckpt'.

This is an example of how to use the MDNN library to convert a tf model to torch:

```
mmconvert -sf tensorflow -in imagenet_resnet_v2_152.ckpt.meta -iw imagenet_resnet_v2_152.ckpt --dstNode MMdnn_Output -df pytorch -om tf_to_pytorch_resnet_152.pth
```

Could anyone help me with it?

Comment: this may help: https://github.com/ysh329/deep-learning-model-convertor

Comment: You can try ONNX as well, should be most reliable